# Import mail attachments at regular intervals of time

Tags: powerbi

I have attachments in the mail which need to be imported at regular intervals of time in power bi is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most efficient way to do this is by using Power Automate (O365 Feature) and create a flow that will save down the attachment automatically to a Folder once an email is received with your parameters.

This should get you on the right track:

https://us.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/289f7f75e2ff4a3183cfd08064bdece6/save-email-attachments-to-the-file-system/

From Power Bi select folder as the data source if you would like to append all the files downloaded - or -
Overwrite the file in the Power Automate Process.

Alternatively - you will need to use a Macro in Outlook to save this file down to a file system. Power Bi cannot read emails directly.